# Replacing Relay with Triac

Tags: ac, control, triac

I am designing a simple on/off type 230V AC voltage control application which with a load of less than 2A. I have been using relays controlled by microcontrollers in my other designs on daily basis, but due to space constraint, I am thinking of using Triac in this design.
I selected [BT134-600E](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ween-semiconductors/BT134-600E-127/1155119) , I am concerned about is the life expectancy of the circuit.
My expectation is 5 years mean life expectancy with 8-10 Hrs of operation/day.
Can anyone suggest what precautions I need to take to make sure the Triac lasts for at least 5 years?
Also, other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Indirect lightning surges need to be considered. [IEC 62000-4-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61000-4-5) should be considered and is highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been using relays controlled by microcontrollers in my other designs on daily basis, but due to space constraint, I am thinking of using Triac in this design.

If you are space constrained I will advice you to use normal relay(Electromagnetic) rather then one with triac based because in later case you have to use opto-coupler for galavanic isolation + snubber circuit for triac + snubber for opto-coupler as recommended in [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/97984.pdf) on page 4.

> My expectation is 5 years mean life expectancy with 8-10 Hrs of operation/day

I can't tell the exact Life time of solid state relay(one with triac based)but surely it is more then the electromagnetic relay.So may be you don't need to take concern about it.

Answer (score 0):

Relay gives galvanic isolation, triac not. Use solid state relay. EM relay life spun measured in turns on-off. Triac is depends on quality.

Answer (score 0):

A relay with a known load and voltage will last a fairly predictable number of operations.

A triac may fail instantly from a transient or keep working for decades. To keep the life long try to minimize the temperature excursions at the die, buy the highest voltage you can and protect it with a MOV or similar device.

Also keep in mind that triacs typically fail "on".